# How to Fill a group of Fabric.Path like any shape or a single path

Tags: angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

While filling a single Fabric.Path object , it fills completely and works fine!

Example,
[**Single Path Fill Example Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxKzL.png)

But , when I fill a group Paths , they obviously act according to their Individual shape .

Example,
  [**Group of Paths Fill Example Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgdwp.png)

I'm using simple fill function of fabricjs.
Secondly , I have to avoid any change in their state. they must stay as a group of paths.

Is there something i did wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fabric does not support what you are trying to do.